# fancy indexing multiple dimensions: Boolean Matrix for hypercube?

Tags: python, numpy

Let us assume the following example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random([100,200,300,400])
c1 = np.arange(0,100,17)
c2 = np.arange(0,100,17)
c3 = np.arange(0,100,17)
c4 = np.arange(0,100,17)
q = (((x[c1,:,:,:])[:,c2,:,:])[:,:,c3,:])[:,:,:,c4]
```

which is the most inefficient way after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743320/numpy-fancy-indexing-in-multiple-dimensions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386822/fast-numpy-fancy-indexing?rq=1), these are telling me that it would be good idea to unravel the 4d array into 1d and then index only in one dimension. So, is there not a better way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) to build the appropriate indices:

```
>>> %timeit q = (((x[c1,:,:,:])[:,c2,:,:])[:,:,c3,:])[:,:,:,c4]
1 loops, best of 3: 237 ms per loop
>>> %timeit q = x[np.ix_(c1, c2, c3, c4)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.3 µs per loop
```

which is orders of magnitude faster but gives the same result:

```
>>> np.allclose((((x[c1,:,:,:])[:,c2,:,:])[:,:,c3,:])[:,:,:,c4], x[np.ix_(c1, c2, c3, c4)])
True
```