# indexing a numpy array with indices from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array "data" with dimensions [t, z, x, y].  The
dimensions represent time (t) and three spatial dimensions (x, y, z).
I have a separate array "idx" of indices with dimensions [t, x, y]
describing vertical coordinates in data: each value in idx describes a
single vertical level in data.

I want to pull out the values from data indexed by idx.  I've done it
successfully using loops (below).  I've read several [SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082939/index-a-numpy-array-with-another-array) and [numpy's indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) but I haven't been able to make it more pythonic/vectorized.

Is there an easy way I'm just not getting quite right?  Or maybe loops
are a clearer way to do this anyway...

```
import numpy as np

dim = (4, 4, 4, 4)  # dimensions time, Z, X, Y

data = np.random.randint(0, 10, dim)
idx = np.random.randint(0, 3, dim[0:3])

# extract vertical indices in idx from data using loops
foo = np.zeros(dim[0:3])
for this_t in range(dim[0]):
    for this_x in range(dim[2]):
        for this_y in range(dim[3]):
            foo[this_t, this_x, this_y] = data[this_t,
                                               idx[this_t, this_x, this_y],
                                               this_x,
                                               this_y]

# surely there's a better way to do this with fancy indexing
# data[idx] gives me an array with dimensions (4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
# data[idx[:, np.newaxis, ...]] is a little closer
# data[tuple(idx[:, np.newaxis, ...])] doesn't quite get it either
# I tried lots of variations on those ideas but no luck yet
```

Comment: `data.swapaxes(0, 1)[idx]`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44868461/901925 does this sort of assignment with a 3d array.  The idea should work with your 4d case.  The idea is to get 3 arrays (from `ogrid`) that let you do `data[I, idx, J, K]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [7]: I,J,K = np.ogrid[:4,:4,:4]
In [8]: data[I,idx,J,K].shape
Out[8]: (4, 4, 4)
In [9]: np.allclose(foo, data[I,idx,J,K])
Out[9]: True
```

`I,J,K` broadcast together to the same shape as `idx` (4,4,4).

More detail on this kind of indexing at

[How to take elements along a given axis, given by their indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868392/how-to-take-elements-along-a-given-axis-given-by-their-indices)

Comment: wow, that's brilliant.  I had to dig into np.ogrid a little to wrap my head around it, but nicely done.  Thanks much.

Comment: Print the `I,J,K` variables.  You can recreate those yourself,with expressions like `np.arange(4)[None,:,None]`.